# transaction in SQL is committed but only 1 of the queries is done correctly

Tags: php, sql

I am having 2 tables, and in the one I want to increment a counter in a specific row while make an insertion in the other one table. I am using php and MySQL and the Engine is InnoDB.

Here is my code:

```
function incrementCommentCounter ($id,$photoId,$text,$date) {
$query1= "UPDATE photos SET comments=comments+1 WHERE IdPhoto=$photoId";
//$query2= "INSERT INTO allComments (IdPhoto,IdUser,comment,date) VALUES ('%s',1,'%s',%s)";

//check if a user ID is passed
//if (!$id) errorJson('Authorization required');

mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");

$result1=mysql_query($query1);
$result2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO allComments (IdPhoto,IdUser,comment,dates) VALUES ('%s',1,'%s','%s')",$photoId,$text,$date);

if (!$result1 || !$result2) {
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
    errorJson($result2['error']);
} else {
    mysql_query("COMMIT");
    print json_encode(array('successful'=>1));
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

thanks.

**Edit:**

Fixed some typos. Now the second query never performs correctly and so none of them is executed. But what is wrong with the second query?

Comment: What database engine are you using? If MySQL, then MyISAM doesn't support transactions, while InnoDB does.... so that kind of information makes a big difference

Comment: @MarkBaker no its InnoDB. Can you give an example of your second comment?

Comment: Are you getting the errorJson returned, or the successful return? Which path of your `if` is the code taking?

Comment: @MarkBaker I am getting the successful return.

Comment: If you're getting the successful return, then the problem is in `if (!result1 || !result2) {`

Comment: @MarkBaker I fixed some typos. the problem seems t be with the second query which always does not execute right now.

Answer (score 0):

The native PHP function `mysql_error` might provide you with valuable hints regarding possible syntax errors in your queries (and other kind of issues)
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-error.php

Besides please consider using mysqli or pdo_mysql as older mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.

In your second query, perhaps you wanted to used a string replacement function like sprintf?

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO allComments (IdPhoto,IdUser,comment,dates) VALUES ('%s',1,'%s','%s')", $photoId, $text, $date);
$result = mysql_query($query);
```